# cursor on secondary screens on anroid

Tags: android

I am attempting to use the Presentation class for Android to display a secondary app on another display which can be navigated with the mouse; however, when I connect a Bluetooth mouse to the phone it only shows the cursor and allows for click inputs on the phone's primary display. Is there a way to override the display the mouse cursor shows up on in such a way that I can feed it my Presentation display information and have it show up on the cast display instead?

Too be honest I haven't tried much because I don't know enough about this topic. im able to launch apps but not control them.